# Is there any way to use Raspberry Pi GPIO pins in Javascript frontend

Tags: javascript, next.js, raspberry-pi, gpio

I was wondering if there exists any way that I can use the Raspberry Pi's GPIO pins in Javascript? I want to read the values of the Raspberry Pi PIR sensor and I really don't want to make it in Python and Javascript and have 2 different applications, I would rather have them together. Also, I don't need a Node.js solution, **exclusively frontend**.

(additional info: Raspberry Pi 3b+ and Next.js)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, that's not possible. You need a backend technology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

There is no API provided by browsers for accessing GPIO devices.